Airflow decorated task type hinting
Take this simple dag, in which one task takes the output of another:
import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@task
def task_that_returns_a_string() -> str:
    return "a string"

@task
def task_that_takes_a_string(arg: str) -> None:
    print(arg)

@dag(
    schedule_interval="@weekly",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
)
def my_dag():
    task_that_takes_a_string(task_that_returns_a_string())

my_dag()

This dag runs fine, but my editor is complaining about the line task_that_takes_a_string(task_that_returns_a_string()):
Argument of type "XComArg" cannot be assigned to parameter "arg" of type "str"
  "XComArg" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportArgumentType

I could of course disable type checking on that line, but then I would miss out on valuable feedback. So what should I change so that I get correct type-hinting feedback?

Pyright/Pylance is correct here ([] denotes an empty ParamSpec):



task
reveal_type(task)
reveal_type(task.__call__)




task_that_returns_a_string
Task[[], str]
Callable[[], XComArg]


task_that_takes_a_string
Task[[str], None]
Callable[[str], XComArg]



That the return value of a task may not be valid as an argument to another task is a known problem.
A Mypy plugin was written to handle this. It used to be delivered with the main package, but was moved to a development-only directory due to some problems. Another issue was opened recently to request that it be published again.
Regardless, even if the plugin were to be published, it wouldn't solve your problem, since you are using Pyright/Pylance and not Mypy. A type-checker-agnostic solution is to use cast():
from typing import cast

task_that_takes_a_string(cast(str, task_that_returns_a_string()))


Thank you for your answer. I guess there's no solution currently to provide type feedback on task arguments. Casting moves the checking of type correctness back to error-prone-me.
